# apk python packages not installing in Alpine Docker Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I have a dockerfile as below:

```
FROM python:3.7.5-alpine3.10

RUN apk update

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apk add --no-cache cython3

CMD [ "sh", "ls"]
```

When I got into the container with `docker run -it --rm mycontainer /bin/sh` cython appears not to be installed. What am I missing?

```
/usr/src/app # which python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/src/app # python
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 21 2019, 20:13:45) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cython'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpine installed python pacakges using this path `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages`, just run the command inside the container and you will see the package is installed. All you need to add this path to the python search path.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache cython3
ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

**PYTHONPATH**

> Augment the default search path for module files. The format is the
>   same as the shell’s PATH: one or more directory pathnames separated by
>   os.pathsep (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on Windows).
>   Non-existent directories are silently ignored.
>
> In addition to normal directories, individual PYTHONPATH entries may
>   refer to zipfiles containing pure Python modules (in either source or
>   compiled form). Extension modules cannot be imported from zipfiles.
>
> The default search path is installation dependent, but generally
>   begins with `prefix/lib/pythonversion` (see PYTHONHOME above). It is
>   always appended to `PYTHONPATH`.
>
> An additional directory will be inserted in the search path in front
>   of `PYTHONPATH` as described above under Interface options. The search
>   path can be manipulated from within a Python program as the variable
>   `sys.path`.

[python envvar PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

**update:**

To work with pip installation you need to use `-m`.

> When called with `-m module-name`, the given module is located on the
>   **Python module path** and executed as a script.

[python3-cmdline](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html)

you can test

```
RUN apk add --no-cache cython3
ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages
RUN python -m pip install requests
RUN python -m pip list
#import test
RUN python -c "import requests"
```

Comment: This does work and I see that cython is installed and I can import it in python, but if I do pip install cython it still installs it. How can I get it to recognize it's already installed?

Comment: are you sure that you still can use pip when you set the obove pythonpath ? I think pip will not be usable, only by calling `python -m pip`

Comment: @LinPy only if I exec into the container it works. `which pip` returns `/usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: If you try `python -m pip install cython` with the ENV is set then you will get that cython is already installed

Comment: Thank you @LinPy, as mentioned by Linpy you need to use `-m` flag.  check the updated answer to work with alpine python packages along with pip.